# Mule : Issue in Outbound HTTPS call

Tags: https, mule

Our Mule application makes an outbound https call to a service. We are getting below error only on some requests,

***“Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. Size of a request header field exceeds server limit”***

From the error message it seems we are more in sending more data in the header.

I searched for the issue and found a relevant post where it says to delete the MULE_SESSION header before the outbound call. Below is the link, also similar post is on SO as well,

http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/how_to_remove_the_mule_session_header_from_a_http_request

I have tried deleting the header using Message transformer but it is not working for me,

```
<message-properties-transformer doc:name="HTTPMuleSessionStripper">
    <delete-message-property key="#[header:outbound:MULE_SESSION]" />
    <delete-message-property key="MULE_SESSION" />
</message-properties-transformer>
```

Also, when I am trying the other way mentioned in the post i.e. specifying the Null session connection, it is not working for https connector or maybe there is a different way of doing it which I am not aware of.

Below does not work,

```
<https:connector name="NoSessionConnector">
      <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler"/>
</https:connector>
```

Interestingly, I compared the MULE_SESSION header just before it makes the Https outbound call of two different messages, one which is working and one which is not working, found they have the same length, so not sure if issue is related to this header.

Can you please suggest any pointers around the issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have doubts that `HTTPMuleSessionStripper` really works. Using the `org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler` is the way to prevent the session to be serializer. Mule may still add the header but it will be empty. Point Mule to another HTTPS (or HTTP) endpoint you control and check the exact state of the headers you're receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologize for posting it incorrectly, what I meant by below (NullSessionHandler) does not work for https is my mule application failed to start after adding this, it was giving me parsing exception.

On checking the issue again, the issue seemed to be with the order of the tags in the Https connector, so service override tag should be the last tag in the connector. (I think this should be defined in the mule schema in mule-module-spring-config.jar, haven't checked though)

Anyways, Thanks for help, its working now.